# Could not connect "org.freedesktop.IBus" to globalEngineChanged(QString) error

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qmake, qt6

I was trying to follow a Qt tutorial but I get this error:

```
Could not connect "org.freedesktop.IBus" to globalEngineChanged(QString)
```

which I don't understand, my code seems fine enough so I believe there is a problem with my `.pro` file or with `Qt Creator` settings, and I don't have enough Qt experience to fix it.

I've tried googling the problem but found no solution.

This is my code:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  // Define the QApplication
  QApplication app (argc, argv);
  // Return the app exec
  return app.exec();
}
```

And this is my `.pro` file

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) : QT += widgets

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

I'm not really doing anything complicated, so I must have missed something or done something wrong.

The tutorial I'm following is [Qt Tutorials For Beginners 3 - First Qt Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JVLO8yBMXA), if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need [ibus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ibus), try purging it:

```
sudo apt purge ibus
```

This was tested on both **Wayland** and **X11**.

See this thread on Qt Forum: [Qt6.5.0 and ibus (Ubuntu)](https://forum.qt.io/topic/144388/qt6-5-0-and-ibus-ubuntu/22).

Issue has been addressed, see [code qt io: qt/qtbase.git: IBus: fix missing Q_SLOTS](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?id=9d031caf09b2c14328268ef0e871efd30e80eab2).